# From "LINQ to SQL" to "Azure Table Storage" or "SQL Data Service"

Tags: linq, azure, cloud, azure-table-storage

I have a Silverlight application where I use LINQ to SQL to store my data. Now I have added this application to an Azure cloud, and want to use an Azure method to store my data.
But I don't know whether I should use "Azure Table Storage" or "SQL Data Service", and how I can use it.

Answer (score 2):

You should use SQL Data Services. I guess by now you know this:

> For the underlying Windows Azure platform, we’re adding FastCGI / PHP support, along with the ability to run full trust .NET applications; SQL Data Services goes relational, allowing you to use the full ADO.NET stack, LINQ to SQL, and so on inside a cloud offering;

[via Tim Sneath mix09 post](http://blogs.msdn.com/tims/archive/2009/03/18/mix09-day-1-keynote-pt-2-scott-guthrie-on-advancing-user-experiences.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a good answer for you, but I do know that Azure Table Storage is for non-relational data tables, meaning that if you need to create relational joins between tables, this most likely won't be the route to go.

As for SQL Data Services, there's a CodePlex project called [PhluffyFotos](http://www.codeplex.com/phluffyfotos) that has a "LINQ to SDS provider" that you might want to check out for inspiration.

> PhluffyFotos is a web 2.0 Picture
>   Gallery Service where users can upload
>   their pictures from the web or mobile
>   device. This sample is designed to
>   demonstrate how you can develop a
>   multi tenant application using SQL
>   Server Data Services (SSDS).
>
> The demo utilizes several technologies
>   including: ASP.NET MVC Preview 4,
>   LINQ, Windows Communication
>   Foundation, Silverlight, Windows
>   PowerShell, and the .NET Compact
>   Framework 3.5.

Comment: I think this is a good way, but I can't find the "LINQ to SDSProvider" in this project, can you help me to find this?

Comment: In the SSDSPictureStore.cs file there's some repository-style code which references an "SsdsContext" object from the Microsoft.Samples.Cloud.Data assembly. I think the code for that assembly (or something like it) can be found in the "SSDS Rest Library" (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ssdsrest)